# QtQuick Controls 2 Style: Material.background and Universal.background NOT working

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside2

I want to change background of Universal style, so buttons color would match the other stuff, but background property does not working:/ Other properties (accent, foreground, and theme) work as it should. Also on the default style I can change colors of my buttons using palette.button: "#color", but I want to use Universal style on which palette.button: "#color" also does not working

My code:

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Window 2.13
import QtQuick.Controls.Universal 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    color: "#786969"
    title: qsTr("Hello World")


    Universal.accent: "Black"               //ok
    Universal.background: "Blue"            //NOT OK
    Universal.foreground: "Yellow"          //ok
    Universal.theme: Universal.Dark         //ok

    Button {
        id: button
        x: 270
        y: 138
        text: qsTr("Button")
    }

    CheckBox {
        id: checkBox
        x: 272
        y: 200
        text: qsTr("Check Box")
    }

    Slider {
        id: slider
        x: 220
        y: 264
        value: 0.5
    }

    Switch {
        id: switch1
        x: 267
        y: 334
        text: qsTr("Switch")
    }
}
```

main.py:

```
import sys
import os

from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide2.QtQuickControls2 import QQuickStyle


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    QQuickStyle.setStyle("Universal")
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "main.qml"))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Printscreen:
[image]

Comment: Is your goal to change the background color of the button?

Comment: Yes, I want to change button background globally

Comment: What do you mean by "globally"?

Comment: For all project - if it is possible, to declare it in the beginning of the qml file so all buttons, checboxes, sliders, etc. would have the same color palette, so I don't need to customize every single component

Comment: I've tested with 5.15 and it doesn't work for me too. Looks like a bug.

Comment: In what version it worked fine?

Comment: @Daniel As I have reviewed the source code I see that in that style the Button has a transparent background, so you see that effect. My recommendation is to use a Pane as the parent of the Button.

Comment: Oooooooh, I got it! I need to place button into Pane and also change its highlighted state to true. Thank you for tip! :D

Nevertheless, it should be possible to customize the button background without using Pane ;)